# How to split string by carriage return and space

Tags: javascript, regex, split

**Why I ask an easy question:**

Hi, lots of people asked how to split an string in javascript by multiple values, but I don't understand how it works the `/[^\w\s]|_/` in the split asked, so I don't know how to modify it so it matches my goal.

**What I need:**

I have a textarea in my html, so the users can write words formatted in multiple ways (always text, if they type numbers it will treated as text).

**My code:**

```
<div class="ui-block-c">
   <textarea id="writtenWord" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>


var writtenWord = document.getElementById("writtenWord");
var theWord = writtenWord.value.toUpperCase();
res = theWord.split(" ");

for (var i = res.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ArrayWords.push(res[i]);
    };
```

**What I want:**

To understand how it works so I can change the conditions + a working example that will split words, even if user press enter key or types 5 spaces...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use regex `/\s+/`

```
res = theWord.split(/\s+/);
```

The above will split on 1 or more spaces. `\s` means a space and `+` is a quantifier meaning match the previous token(in this case space(`\s`)) 1 or more times.

Also you just need

```
ArrayWords = res;
```

There is no need of looping and pushing. Another way of doing is to replace more than one spaces with just one space and splitting on just a single space

```
res = theWord.replace(/\s+/," ").split(" ");
```

Comment: And a return key will be taken as multiple spaces??

Comment: @Sascuash it will be splitted upon too.

Comment: Great! Thanks, you were a lot of help!

Comment: I just have tryed it, but doesn't take the "enter key". Here: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) I found that \r is what I want to take so I can split it

Comment: How do I add this other argument?

Comment: @Sascuash try `split(/\s+|\n/)`

Comment: It worked perfectly with `replace(/\s+/," ").split(/\s+|\n/)`